# Can <lightning:recordViewForm> be used without <lightning:outputField>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, spring18, lightning-recordviewform

I am creating my own custom Organization__c record page for a community.

I am using [lightning:recordViewForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordViewForm.htm) and [lightning:outputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_outputField.htm) for all the fields that I want to display, but, I have a few fields that I want to display in a different way - not as standard `lightning:outputField`:

[image]

As you can see from the image - in the red square, the text is built from 2 fields - OrganizationNumber__c and Name, and I want to show these 2 fields like that.

So I want bigger text size, no label and text color, and I cannot find a way to do that with `lightning:outputField`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to achieve that - with `lightning:outputField`?
2. Is there a way to achieve that without the use of `lightning:outputField`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `<lightning:outputField fieldName="name" variant="label-hidden"/>` to remove label.

For bold / italics / height, use CSS using **font-weight**, **font-style** properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not easily without messing with style in order to replicate SLDS components as @Ayem suggested. I would not go down this path.
2. I recommend that you use a combination of `lightning:recordViewForm` and [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) (that is the Lightning Data Service aka LDS). Using both wouldn't cause a significant performance degradation since `lightning:recordViewForm` relies on LDS so they both share the same cache. You could use the data loaded by LDS into an attribute and inject it in any component.